# What values for HORZRES, VERTRES, LOGPIXELSX,LOGPIXELSY, etc I need to give to print photo whith fixed size?

Tags: python

I need to print 1920x1080 photo on A4 using python win32print, but don't understend how to calculate printable area, size and margins. I've tried to read documentation but still no luck
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPCWw.png)